# Netbeans told that "declared variable" is a package that does not exist

Tags: java, jtable, netbeans-7, listselectionlistener

[image]

It happened when I tried to use a ListSelectionModel.

Did I made some mistake?

Comment: post the code please ... +1 for XP :D

Comment: The problem is fixed,thank you. But I still wonder because I use to make an operation in the class block and It's OK until this time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed the statement at the wrong spot:

```
class X {

    HERE - WHERE THE FIELD DECLARATIONS GO

    X() {
        STATEMENT SHOULD GO HERE
    }
```

The compiler thinks to deal with a declaration, starting with a class, which may be `x.y.z.C`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke the statement in a code block such as a method or constructor rather than the class block.

```
class AdminConsole ... {

    void initComponents() {
       ...
       table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
       ...
    }
}
```

Side note: `setSelectionMode` is undefined for `ListSelectionModel` - instead it needs to be invoked on the [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionMode%28int%29)

Comment: Oh, I see. It really shoud be invoked on the JTable.